# MySQl/Laravel: check the changed column before updating the record

Tags: mysql, laravel, logging, enter

I have a table `abc` which has several fields.

I need to fetch the column or columns (except: `id`, `created_at` & `updated_at`) which have been updated and store the existing value along with the column name in a `logs` table corresponding to that selected record before updating it in that table.

For example:
**Table: abc**

```
id: 1
name: 'Old name'
mobile: 9876543210
address: 'Abc-123'
...
created_at: 'Sometime'
updated_at: 'Sometime'

update:
    name: 'new name'
    mobile: 1234567890
```

**Table: logs** should have

```
column | value
name   | Old name

column | value
mobile | 9876543210
```

However, I can save the entire record in the table, which will be lot easier, but that will just be the waste of space/memory. Also, it will be difficult to determine which value was exactly changed at that point of time without any algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

`isDirty()` method is use to check  if the model or any of the given attribute(s) have been modified.

it will return true if name chagned  : `$model->isDirty('name')`

you can also get Old value using `getOriginal()` method

```
Ex  : $old_name = $model->getOriginal('name');
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this